# Anchor Tag Helpers Trigger Pop-up Modal but not the Associated Controller Action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason, the link below is triggering the bootstrap modal pop-up but is not hitting the controller action to grab the data necessary to populate the modal. I have several other modals set up in a similar fashion that are working as expected. Please take a look at my code:

*_EventsPartial.cshtml (partial on homepage containing link)*

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<table class="table table-hover">
    @foreach (var calendarEvent in Model.CalendarEvents)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="date-col">
                <a class="view-event-anywhere" asp-controller="Calendar" asp-action="ViewEvent" asp-route-id="@calendarEvent.Id">
                    <span class="date">@ViewHelpers.FormatShortDate(calendarEvent.Start)</span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="view-event-anywhere" asp-controller="Calendar" asp-action="ViewEvent" asp-route-id="@calendarEvent.Id">
                    <span class="date-description">@calendarEvent.Title</span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The homepage renders just fine and when I hover over the link, the URL looks correct:
[image: link]

*CalendarController.cs*

```
<!-- language: c# -->

// using statements and namespace omitted

[Route("/calendar")]
[Authorize(Policy = "NetContent")]
public class CalendarController : Controller
{
    private ICalendarEventRepository _eventRepo;

    public CalendarController(ICalendarEventRepository eventRepo)
    {
        _eventRepo = eventRepo;
    }

    ...

    [HttpGet("view_event/{id}"), AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ViewEvent(int id)
    {
        var requestedEvent = _eventRepo.GetById(id);
        if (requestedEvent != null)
        {
            ViewData["CalendarEvent"] = requestedEvent;
            return PartialView("_ViewEventAnywhere");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

I inserted a breakpoint on the first line inside the `ViewEvent()` function but the code is never executed after the link is triggered.

*_Layout.cshtml*

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
@using Laramie.Net.Features.Calendar

<div id="ViewEventAnywhereModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        @Html.Partial("/Features/Calendar/_ViewEventAnywhere.cshtml")
    </div>
</div>
```

*_ViewEventAnywhere.cshtml*

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
@{
    var selectedEvent = ViewData["CalendarEvent"] as CalendarEvent;
}

@if (selectedEvent != null)
{
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title">@selectedEvent.Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        ...

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

*site.js*

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// View Event Anywhere Modal
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.view-event-anywhere', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#ViewEventAnywhereModal');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.close', function () {
        $('#ViewEventAnywhereModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#ViewEventAnywhereModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
})
```

If I remove the `view-event-anywhere` class from the link the controller action is triggered but the pop-up modal is not, so I'm guessing the issue is with the JavaScript? I must be missing something because it's the same JavaScript code I used for the other modals (with the exception of the class and id names) which are working. If anyone is able to point out my mistake, I'd greatly appreciate it!

**UPDATE:**
I'm adding the code for a similar modal implemented in this same project that is working as expected. I can't figure out what the difference is between the two to cause the one above not to work.

*_Layout.cshtml*

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<!-- link in navbar -->
<li>
    <a class="upload-file" asp-controller="FileManager" asp-action="UploadFile">Upload a File</a>
</li>

<!-- modal div -->
<div id="UploadFileModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        @Html.Partial("/Features/FileManager/_UploadFileModal.cshtml", new FileManagerViewModel())
    </div>
</div>
```

*FileManagerController.cs*

```
<!-- language: c# -->
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UploadFile()
{
    PopulateCategoryDropDownList();
    return PartialView("_UploadFileModal");
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(FileManagerViewModel model)
{

...

}

private void PopulateCategoryDropDownList(int selectedCategory = 0)
{
    var categories = _categoryRepo.GetAll();
    ViewData["CategoryList"] = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "Name", selectedCategory);
}
```

*_UploadFileModal.cshtml*

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
@model FileManagerViewModel

@{ 
    var categories = ViewData["CategoryList"] as SelectList;
}

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Upload a File</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="FileManager" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-antiforgery="true">

        ...

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

*site.js*

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// Upload File Modal
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.upload-file', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#UploadFileModal');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.close', function () {
        $('#UploadFileModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.submit-file', function () {
        $('#UploadFileModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#UploadFileModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
})
```

Comment: So what is your expected behavior ? When user clicks on the link, it should navigate to `/calendar/view_event/{id}` ?  Currently you have js code (the one you shared) is preventing it.

Comment: You said  removing the class `view-event-anywhere` ,everything works as expected. So what is the problem.

Comment: It's a pop-up modal, so the expected behavior is that it would hit the action to grab the data and then pass it to the modal that is triggered via the javascript. The modal is being triggered, but the data is not being retrieved via the controller.

Comment: Your action method returns a partial view. Currently your code renders the markup needed for the modal dialog (in the layout) when `ViewData["CalendarEvent"]` has a valid CalendarEvent object.  That means, after setting the ViewData Item in your `ViewEvent` method, you should return a View, not a partial view so that the layout code will execute and render the markup needed for the modal dialog. I am still not sure how the modal is being fired after the page is rendered!

Comment: That makes sense, but the action method is not currently being triggered at all. Let me know if it would be helpful for me to add an example of a similar modal dialog that I implemented in this project that is working as expected.

Comment: just remove the `view-event-anywhere` class from your a tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a bootstrap issue. I had to move the `<div class=modal-content">` tag outside of the `if` statement in the *_ViewEventAnywhere.cshtml* file. It was preventing bootstrap from functioning properly.